# open cv c++ face recognition giving unexpected results

Tags: c++, opencv

this is my code

```
#include "facerec.h"

Ptr<FaceRecognizer> jarvis;

void initJarvis(){
    jarvis=createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    //jarvis->set("threshold",6000);

    if(fileExists("jarvis-data.xml")){
        jarvis->load("jarvis-data.xml");
    }
}

void saveJarvisData(){
    jarvis->save("jarvis-data.xml");
}

/*void trainJarvis(int id){
    vector<Mat> images;
    vector<int> labels;
    int pno;
    char debugout[100];
    char imgpath[30];
    FILE *fp=fopen("imglist.txt","r");
    while(fscanf(fp,"%d %s",&pno,imgpath)==2){  
        if(pno==id){

            sprintf(debugout,"%d %s\n",pno,imgpath);
            OutputDebugStringA(debugout);
            images.push_back(imread(imgpath,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE));
            labels.push_back(pno);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    try{
        jarvis->train(images,labels);
    }catch(Exception e){
        char msg[100];
        sprintf(msg,"%s",e.msg);
        MessageBoxA(NULL,msg,"error",0);
    }
}
*/
void trainJarvis(){
    vector<Mat> images;
    vector<int> labels;
    int pno;
    char debugout[100];
    char imgpath[30];
    FILE *fp=fopen("imglist.txt","r");
    while(fscanf(fp,"%d %s",&pno,imgpath)==2){  

            sprintf(debugout,"%d %s\n",pno,imgpath);
            OutputDebugStringA(debugout);
            images.push_back(imread(imgpath,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE));
            labels.push_back(pno);

    }
    fclose(fp);
    try{
        jarvis->train(images,labels);
    }catch(Exception e){
        char msg[100];
        sprintf(msg,"%s",e.msg);
        MessageBoxA(NULL,msg,"error",0);
    }
}

int recognize(){
     double confidence;
      int label=-1;
    Mat img=imread("image.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    int prediction;
    try{

        jarvis->predict(img,prediction,confidence);
    }catch(Exception e){
        char msg[100];
        sprintf(msg,"%s",e.msg);
        MessageBoxA(NULL,msg,"error",0);
    }

    char temp[40];
    sprintf(temp,"Label : %d \nConfidence : %f",prediction,confidence);
    MessageBoxA(NULL,temp,"Prediction",0);
return prediction;

}
```

i have stored 15 images per person which are in greyscale. for this i have followed shervin emamis [tutorial](http://www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html)
i get confidence values from 4000-8000

how do i make it predict faces with better accuracy

Comment: Uh-huh. What's your question? You need to ask it explicitly, rather than implicitly. I could imagine several potential questions - with the chance that none of them are what you're actually wondering.

Comment: your numbers sound pretty reasonable.

Comment: any ideas on getting better accuracy. 6 out of 10 times i get the wrong label(prediction)